# Test sql connect without using System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How to test sql connection without using "System.Data.SqlClient"?

I want to check if the input ip, databasename, username and password of database is correct. I always used `SqlConnection` like this:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("network address=192.168.1.120; password=userpassword; user id=username; database=myDB");
```

But now I don't want to test sql server connection with this code.

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] as a start..

Comment: I used "System.Configuration"'s classes but I couldn't find any way to do this.

Comment: What type of SQL server are you trying to connect to? MySQL, SQL server etc?

Comment: SQL server. If it helps SQL server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use telnet to check the connectivity:

```
telnet yourhostorip 1433
```

And you can use [sqlcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx) to test both the authentication and the connectivity:

```
sqlcmd -S yourhostorip -U username -P password
```

**Example** how you can use it in C#:

```
var sqlProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
sqlProcess.FileName = "SQLCMD.EXE";
sqlProcess.Arguments = String.Format("-S {0} -U {1} -P {2}",
                                    server,
                                    user,
                                    password);
Process.Start(sqlProcess);
```

Comment: It's true but I need to use "System.Data.SqlClient" in my code. I don't want to use it.

Comment: But you say in your question that you don't want to use System.Data.SqlClient? I feel a bit of inconsistency here.

Comment: Yes but i don't know how to use this sqlcmd without "System.Data.SqlClient"? Can you write some example?

Comment: Added an example as requested!

Answer (score 0):

You can always use others

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.OleDb;
```